# Unexpected results when initializing and displaying a vector of integers

Tags: c++

I am running this loop to get the labels of connected components (Opencv's connectedComponentsWithStats) which are larger than some threshold "areaVal" in a separate vector.
however, when I tested the loop, I got some unexpected astronomical numbers, and I got a handful of zeros, which is excluded from the loop in the first place.

on top of that, when i run the same code twice, I get different values in labelIndex vector!

I am desperate for help.

```
vector<int> labelIndex; 
//starting from 1 to exclude the background label
cout << "Number of labels: " << nLabels << ". Entering loop\n\n"; //checkpoint
for (int i=1; i<nLabels; i++)
{
    //cout << i << ") "; //checkpoint
    int area = statsv.at<int>(i, CC_STAT_AREA);
    if (area >= areaVal)
    {
        labelIndex.push_back(i);
        cout << labelIndex[i] << "   "; //checkpoint
    }
}
```

[Image of the different results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuB6Z.png)

Comment: You are accessing your vector out of bounds.

Comment: `cout << labelIndex[i] << "   "; //checkpoint` should be just `cout << i << "   "; //checkpoint`

Comment: What has this code to do with opencv actually?

Answer (score 1):

You're accessing `labelIndex` out of bounds when you did this, since `i` starts at 1:

`cout << labelIndex[i] << "   "; //checkpoint`

If your goal is to print the last value added to the vector, then the following is much safer:

`cout << labelIndex.back() << "   "; //checkpoint`

Please see the [std::vector::back()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/back) function documentation.